# Can we access the respective controller of the view inside the init hook of the view

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a case were I need to choose the template of the view based on the initial property value of the controller. Thus I need to access the controller while I am inside the init hook of the view but when i access the controller it returns "null".

```
MyApp.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
  templateVersion: 'small'
});

MyApp.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({
  init: function(){
    this._super();
    console.log('Controller is: ',this.get('controller'));
    if(this.get('controller').get('templateVersion') == 'small')
    {
      this.set('templateName', 'application-small');
    } else {
      this.set('templateName', 'application-bigger');
    }
  }
});
```

This is not the real case but an example for the real scenario.
For an example I have setup a jsbin [**here**](http://jsbin.com/ahiqen/9/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess a more appropriate way of doing this would be by determine dynamically the `templateName`, something like the following:

```
MyApp.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: function() {
    if (this.get("controller.templateVersion") == "small") {
        return "application-small";
    } else {
        return "application-bigger";
    }
  }.property('controller.templateVersion')
});
```

Doing it this way you dont need to hook into the `init` function and thus not having your controller properties available.

Here your updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/obivoq/2/edit).

### **Update**

After your last comment I realized that the *delay* is the important part to make your use case work, here is an improved version which indeed changes even if the `templateVersion` is initially not defined and get's setted with some delay, this time we observe the `templateName` property of the view and invoke a `rerender`.

```
MyApp.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: function() {
    if (this.get("controller.templateVersion") == "small") {
      return "application-small";
    } else {
      return "application-bigger";
    }
  }.property('controller.templateVersion'),
  templateChanged: function() {
    this.rerender();
  }.observes('templateName')
});
```

And here another [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/obivoq/6/edit) with the new version with a simulated delay of 2 seconds, but it could be whatever value.

Hope it helps.

Comment: would it work even if there is some delay in templateVersion value fetching?

Comment: I guess yes, since it's a computed property, but sincerely haven't tested this use case

Comment: not sure but I guess it won't work because ember uses templateName property to search for a template for a view and once done changing, the template name doesn't affect the template as it is not recalculated and re-rendered. Thus whatever name it gets in the beginning is set as its template. Irrespective of the change later.

Comment: @guleria, I've updated my answer to fit your use case more closely, have a look.

Comment: that fitted exactly to my case. Thanks a lot.